# zoom accessibility issue navigate Participants panel to open More button for selecting Clear All Feedback

Tags: accessibility, zoom-meeting

Is it just me or does the zoom app really not support the Tab key for navigating outside the active focused Participants panel?

To reach the buttons underneath i.e. "More" button to select the "Clear All Feedback"?

[image: zoom participants panel active focus]
[image: more button]

I want to do this given there is no shortcut or other workaround to automate clearing feedback via a custom shortcut / apple script (that I'd like to use via elgato stream deck). There has been [feature suggestion](https://devforum.zoom.us/t/clear-all-feedback-keyboard-shortcut/45491) but nothing happened since 2021, no surprise.

Note: I currently had no second participant in the meeting thus "Clear All Feedback" obviously is greyed out, i just can't reach the menu at all.

UPDATE: Enabling "Full Keyboard Access" in Accessibility makes it work, but always has elements now selected when browsing thus not practical.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you set to 'Full Keyboard Access:All controls'? Before Ventura isn't wasn't easy to find, I imagine it's even more well-hidden in Ventura. [Can't get to a Ventura Mac right this minute.] Here it is prior to that - https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SDne.png

Comment: Indeed, Thanks that worked, you're the man. I'm already on Monterey and this is disabled by default i guess, wow surprising it wouldn't work OOTB. BUT this will always have elements in focus which is not practical for regular users who don't need Accessibility.